# pandas cannot read csv in same directory

Tags: python, file, path

i am having this issue since like 2 months, it didnt bother me at first but now that im trying to import a file with pd or even a normal txt file with `open()` it gives me this Exception:

```
  File "C:\Users\lcc_zarkos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 642, in get_handle
    handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'marketing.xlsx'
```

if i use the full path it just runs normally.
people would say "just use full path then" but this is a really bad solution when it comes to using this program on multiple devices with different paths or stuff like that
so i hope you have any solutions.
here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('marketing.xlsx')
```

image:
[vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4URbx.png)
[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7V1g.png)

edit:
it has none to do with the code itself but more like windows or my pc

Comment: I'd try printing out `os.getcwd()` and `os.listdir()` to see if you're actually executing in the path you expect, and the file is present according to the interpreter.

Comment: What @SamMorgan said but... are you sure that's a CSV file? The `.xlsx` filename extension indicates that that's an Excel workbook. CSV (comma-separated-values) means a delimited text file. An Excel workbook is a different beast.

Comment: it is indeed and excel file but that dosent change anything because in my code i typed `read_csv('marketing.xlsx')`

Comment: and `os.listdir()` returns `['main.py', 'marketing .xlsx', 'requirements.txt', 'setup.py']`

Comment: os.getcwd() returns C:\Users\lcc_zarkos\Desktop\df-set

Comment: The `os.listdir` output you posted has a space after `marketing`, is that a typo ?

Answer (score 1):

`FileNotFoundError` means that the file path you've given to pandas point to an non existing file.

In your case this can be caused by:

- you haven't put your file in the current working directory of your script
- you have a typo in your file name

In both case, I would print the file path, and check the location using a file browser, you will find your mistake:

```
print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'marketing.xlsx'))
```

Answer (score 0):

i see a spaces in the file name there. I tried on mac, and it works very well.
['main.py', 'marketing .xlsx', 'requirements.txt']